# Test if two floating point numbers within 1 ULP

Tags: python, floating-point

How to find out whether the difference between two floating-point numbers is at most 1 ULP?

Something like the code below, which (ignores the signs and exponent, and) extracts the binary of mantissa, but slightly less awful:

```
a = int(<float>.hex().lstrip('-').lstrip('0x')[1:].lstrip('.')[:-3].rstrip('+').rstrip('p'), 16)
b = int(<float>.hex().lstrip('-').lstrip('0x')[1:].lstrip('.')[:-3].rstrip('+').rstrip('p'), 16)
print abs(a - b) <= 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NumPy, you can get the next floating-point number after a given number:

```
# Test whether taking the smallest possible step from b in the direction of a gets you a.
# Special case: If b == a, then np.nextafter(b, a) == a
a == np.nextafter(b, a)
```

(This might not quite be what you want if, say, the two numbers have different ULPs, or if one is an infinity.)

Comment: Why would it be a problem, if "the two numbers have different ULPs"? And thank you very much for the answer, but I would prefer to use only Python stdlib, rather than NumPy...

Comment: @EcirHana: If a and b are within one a-ULP of each other, but not one b-ULP of each other, what should happen? This check gives False. Maybe you don't want that.

Comment: I see. In that case, my question is wrong and your answer is correct :).

Comment: There is no problem when their ULPs don't agree. If there are two representable numbers where there is no other number between them, one of them must be a power of 2.